# Is it possible to save a trained layer to use layer on Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I haven't used Keras and I'm thinking whether to use it or not.

I want to save a trained layer to use later. For example:

1. I train a model.
2. Then, I gain a trained layer `t_layer`.
3. I have another model to train which consists of `layer1`, `layer2`, `layer3` .
4. I want to use `t_layer` as `layer2` and not to update this layer(i.e. `t_layer` does not learn any more).

This may be an odd attempt, but I want to try this. Is this possible on Keras?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is.

You will probably have to save the layer's weights and biases instead of saving the layer itself, but it's possible.

Keras also allows you to [save entire models](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model).

Suppose you have a model in the var `model`:

```
weightsAndBiases = model.layers[i].get_weights()
```

This is a list of numpy arrays, very probably with two arrays: weighs and biases. You can simply use `numpy.save()` to save these two arrays and later you can create a similar layer and give it the weights:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model

inp = Input(....)    
out1 = SomeKerasLayer(...)(inp)  
out2 = AnotherKerasLayer(....)(out1)
.... 
model = Model(inp,out2)
#above is the usual process of creating a model    

#supposing layer 2 is the layer you want (you can also use names)    

weights = numpy.load(...path to your saved weights)    
biases = numpy.load(... path to your saved biases)
model.layers[2].set_weights([weights,biases])
```

You can make layers untrainable (must be done before the model compilation):

```
model.layers[2].trainable = False
```

Then you compile the model:

```
model.compile(.....)
```

And there you go, a model, whose one layer is untrainable and has weights and biases defined by you, taken from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a common practice in transfer learning, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/exporting_tf2_saved_model).
Thjs piece_to_share below can be one or more layers.

```
piece_to_share = tf.keras.Model(...)
full_model = tf.keras.Sequential([piece_to_share, ...])
full_model.fit(...)
piece_to_share.save(...)
```