# TensorFlow: What is the easiest way to incorporate predictions from one model in the training of a new model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

What is the simplest way to use `tf.estimator` trained model A during the training of another model B?

The weights in model A are fixed. In model B, I would like to take some inputs, compute, feed these results into model A, then do some more computations on the output.

A simple example:

ModelA returns `tf.matmul(input,weights)`

In ModelB, I would like to do the following:

```
  x1 = tf.matmul(new_inputs,new_weights1)
  x2 = modelA(x1) # with fixed weights
  return tf.matmul(x2,new_weights2)
```

But with more complicated models A and B, each of which is trained as a `tf.estimator` (though I'm happy to not use estimators if there's another easy solution -- I'm using them because I would like to use ML Engine).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50084579/tensorflow-use-a-tf-estimator-trained-model-within-another-tf-estimator-model-f) question is related, but the proposed solution does not work for training model B, because the gradients of tf.py_func are [None]. I have tried registering a gradient for tf.py_func, but this fails with

> Unsupported object type Tensor

I have also tried `tf.import_graph_def` for model A, but this seems to load the pretrained graph, but not the actual weights.

Answer (score 0):

For model composability, Keras works a whole lot better. You can convert a Keras model to estimator:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/new-in-tensorflow-14-converting-a-keras-model-to-a-tensorflow-estimator

So you can still train on ML Engine.

With Keras, it is then just a matter of loading the intermediate layers' weights and biases from a checkpoint and make that layer non-trainable. See:

[Is it possible to save a trained layer to use layer on Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644800/is-it-possible-to-save-a-trained-layer-to-use-layer-on-keras)